# SwiftUI: Presenting View Over Any View when app enters background

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to display a view every time the app come to the foreground  (ie a password view where you need to use faceid/passcode to use the app, banking apps do that often). My initial idea was to present a fullscreencover at the root and display the screen but that solution does not work if a child is presenting a fullscreencover. Applying the `.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification))` on the child view does work but I believe it might get messy if I need to add it to every child fullscreencover for it to display.

Thanks for your help! Maybe I'm approaching the problem incorrectly...I was also thinking of pushing it to the navstack instead of using a fullscreenCover.

In UIKit you could get the top view controller and present the view when the app enters background mode but that's not the case with SwiftUI - or maybe I'm missing something?

Below is my example:

```
@main
struct NavApp: App {
    @State var isPresentingParentfullScreen = false
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresentingParentfullScreen, content: {
                    FullCoverViewDidEnterBg()
                })
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification)) { _ in
                    isPresentingParentfullScreen = true
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresenting = true
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {

                Button("Present Full Cover") {
                    isPresenting.toggle()
                }
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresenting, content: {
                FullCoverView()
            })
        }
    }
}

struct FullCoverView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        Text("FullCoverView")
        Button("dismiss") {
            dismiss()
        }
    }
}
// how can I present this screen everytime the app comes to the foreground?
// I know this foreground event will only get triggered once since the presenting flag is not reset.
struct FullCoverViewDidEnterBg: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("FullCoverViewDidEnterBg")
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it working by have MainScene and an OverlayScene on top on the MainScene.

Comment: Hi! I'm having the exact same need and i'm not finding a good solution. Could you ellaborate a bit more on how did you achieve this with SwiftUI?